# google maps jquery plugin with json, php, mysql overwritten markers

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, google-maps

I am using jquery plugin to for google maps, trough json I am getting GPS coordinates and infos for the events. The problem is when I have 2 same markers (GPS coordinates are the same) but info of event is different, for example:

`{"markers":[ { "latitude":57.7973333, "longitude":12.0502107, "content":"Representing event 1 10:00-12:00" }, { "latitude":57.7973333, "longitude":12.0502107, "content":"Representing event 2 - 15:00-16:00"  } 
]}`

The problem is that markers are overwritten, I get info only for one event on one position, and not 2 events, how could I get one 1 marker with all the infos on the map, something like 1 marker with one info box where I would have this info:

Representing event 1 10:00-12:00

Representing event 2 - 15:00-16:00

My code is like that now - i think this could be done with mysql but not really sure how, is there a way to check the gps coordinates and if there same take all content and store in one field???:

`$return_arr = array();`

`$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT title,event,SUBSTRING_INDEX(gps,',',1) as latitude,SUBSTRING_INDEX(gps,',',-1) as longitude,gps FROM termin,event WHERE gps IS NOT NULL AND gps!='' AND event_id_fk=event_id") or die(mysql_error());`

`while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['latitude'] = $row['latitude'];
    $row_array['longitude'] = $row['longitude'];
    $row_array['content'] = "<b>".$row['title']."</b><br/>".$row['event'];`

```
array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
```

`}`

`echo '{"markers":'.json_encode($return_arr).'}';`

What I would like is something like this, one record:

"latitude":57.7973333, "longitude":12.0502107, "content":"Representing event 1 10:00-12:00 Representing event 2 - 15:00-16:00"

or is there some other way to check it with loop? that would be better I think, because than I would be able to use html for every event

Comment: An unrelated comment but you should use MySQLi or PDO API. [Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: yes I have changed that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer with group_concat

Answer (score 0):

As I know it is IMPOSSIBLE to implement it with MySQL. 
In my projects I merged records using PHP.

Each record you have to compare with the previous. If the are equal - do don't have to push new value to array. Just add content data to previous array element.